# Drag and drop with jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I have one calendar on which i have events at particular time on that calendar.

In the design of that calendar i used table. Each td states a particular time for the particular resource.

Now i want to add drag and drop facility to this calendar so that users can reschedule their events by drag and drop.

JS Files are :

```
 - jQuery UI 1.8.11
 - jQuery JavaScript Library v1.4.1
```

I am using this code for drag and drop :

```
$(".event1").draggable();
$(".timetd").droppable({
        accept: '.event1',
        hoverClass: 'droppable-hover',
        drop: function(event, ui) {
           alert('yes');
        }
    });
```

But this is not working means nothing is happened when i drag div.

Can anyone please help me ?

My code is like this fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/mausami/xp786/

Comment: Are you using this: http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

Comment: No i am not. I have code it in html, jquery and PHP.

Comment: Your fiddle will not load properly.

Comment: Ya it happened with me also. I don't know why ?? I have to stop script for it. May be it will works for you also.

Comment: It's because there is a MASSIVE amount of HTML in that fiddle. You appear to have done an incredible amount of work on this already. Does jQ 1.4.1 work with jQUI 1.8.11??

Comment: yes with JQ 1.8.11 it works. you can see it in yeyene's fiddle also. http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/xp786/1/

Comment: That easily might be the most code I've seen in a jsfiddle example. Try condensing that!

Answer (score 0):

#### Update Answer

Check here , DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/xp786/4/

*Try to drop on 08:30 time slot.

And you cannot drop because there is no `.timetd` class to drop yet.

```
$(function() {
    $( ".event1" ).draggable();
    $( ".timetd b" ).droppable({
      accept: '.event1',
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            alert('yes');
        }
    });
});
```

[image]

Comment: Hey thanks yeyene. But its not doing anything on drop. I want to get td's class on drop of event div.

Comment: your tds dont have any .timetd class yet.

Comment: it has. It has two classes at moment. Its messy in my fiddle. My td design is : <td id="resource10" style="margin:0; padding:0; border-right:1px solid #AED0EA;" class="r10min_1230 timetd"></td>

i want to get this class : r10min_1230

Comment: check my update answer and demo again, you need to use <b> tag to drop. Try to drop on 08:30 time slot.

Comment: i gave background color red to see .timetd class, on 08:30 slot, you can see a thin red line only, inside this td, there is <b> tag, you can drop on this?

Comment: still nothing happened. I tried in your fiddle also. but nothing got alert on drop.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/xp786/4/ , see the screenshot in answer, you have to drop in the middle, not sure because of your drag div.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33317/discussion-between-mausami-and-yeyene)